# Questions on number operations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I took this practice text from University of Houston to prepare for the texes 4-8 math test. They do not show the correct answer if you get a question wrong. Can someone tell me the answer to these questions? 
The first question is solve -5^0 + 10^-1.
I said it was 11/10. I thought -5^0 was 1 and 10^-1 was 1/10. But I got it wrong.

The second question is more tricky. It asks, "Find all complex solutions to the equation. x^2 + 81 = 0. 
I said x=9 and x=-9. But I got it wrong. I noticed that it said "complex" solutions to the equation. But, there aren't any complex solutions to the problem correct? Complex means it has imaginary and real numbers in it, correct?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @user45878: for the first, you need to consider when to apply the minus sign.  For the second, you have a typo ($91$) and you are taking the square root of the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, $-5^0=-(5^0)$  For the second, $9^2=81$, but you want $x^2=-81$, so you need a factor of $i$.

Comment: I see what you are saying about -81. Thank you for your help :) And I understand about -5^0 as well.